# Kendo UI (jquery) template getting value when property name is in a string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, kendo-ui

I'm working on building a KendoGrid that has a variable number of columns that aren't known until runtime. I have code in place that takes the first row of the data and generates the schema and column information, which gets attached to the Kendo DataSource before the grid is wired up. I'm also using a proxy to inject the column field and display name into the template.

What I'm having a hard time dealing with is not knowing how to reference the row data directly, without knowing the property name. I know in a normal kendo template, you could do `#= WorkItemId =` to get the value itself, but I'm looking for something along the lines of `#= model[item.field] #` so I can pull the values dynamically.

Is this possible? I've tried `this`, but that points back to the values I inject with the $.proxy. I've also tried `item`, `model`, etc. but nothing seems to give me what I'm looking for.

```
// kendo.datasource
for (i = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) {
    // add template to the cell
    columns[i].template = $.proxy(
        kendo.template($('#QueueTemplate_Default').html()),
        {
            columnName: columns[i].title,
            fieldName: columns[i].field
        }
    );
}

// cell template
<script id="QueueTemplate_Default" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    #= {{model/this/something}}[item.columnName] #
</script>

// example schema that comes back from the controller
{
"schema": {
    "data": "Data",
    "total": "Total",
    "model": {
        "id": "WorkItemId",
        "field": {
            "WorkItemId": {
                "editable": false,
                "type": "number"
            },
            "WorkItem": {
                "editable": false,
                "type": "string"
            },
            // edited for brevity
        }
    }
},
"columns": [
    {
        "field": "WorkItemId",
        "title": "Work Item Id",
        "template": null
    },
    {
        "field": "WorkItem",
        "title": "Work Item",
        "template": null
    },
    // edited for brevity
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a template, you have `data` object. In fact you can only access all properties by names like `#= PropertyA #` because the code is wrapped into a `with(data) { ... }`([reference](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.core.js#L342)) statement. So doing `#= PropertyA #` is the same as `#= data.PropertyA #`. Note that [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) is obsolete.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    let data = {
        propertyName: 'myProperty',
        myProperty: 'myValue'
      };
    
    console.log(kendo.template("#= data[data.propertyName] #")(data));
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ANAZegEk)

Your case I think can be like:

```
<script id="QueueTemplate_Default" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    #= data[item.columnName] #
</script>
```

Comment: That absolutely did the trick! I tried dozens of ways to reference the kendo data itself, but never just `data`! Thank you!

Comment: @DanChampagne when you get stuck in cases like that, try checking out their source code, it might help sometimes.